# Is there a way to interpolate variables into a python string WITHOUT using the print function?

Tags: python, string, variables, format, string-interpolation

Every example I have seen of Python string variable interpolation uses the `print` function.

For example:

```py
num = 6

# str.format method
print("number is {}".format(num))

# % placeholders
print("number is %s"%(num))

# named .format method
print("number is {num}".format(num=num))
```

Can you interpolate variables into strings without using `print`?

Comment: `"number is {num}".format(num=num)` gives you a string. `print` just prints it. `s = "number is {num}".format(num=num); print(s)` would work fine.

Comment: *Every example I have seen of Python string variable interpolation uses the print function.* That's to show the output of interpolation.

Comment: You can do it in many places. Assign to a variable for instance:`foo = "number is {num}".format(num=num)`. Use in a different function `foo("number is {num}".format(num=num)`)`. You can even iterate them `for c in "number is {num}".format(num=num): `. In this case "number is {num}" is a string object with a `.format` method.

Comment: `str=f"number is {num}"`

Comment: @Mayur Please don't redeclare [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str)…

Comment: I see str() type is python. better `s=f"number is {num}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok...so, it's kind of easy.

The old method:

```py
num = 6
mystr = 'number is %s' % num
print(mystr) # number is 6
```

The newer `.format` method:

```py
num = 6
mystr = "number is {}".format(num)
print(mystr) # number is 6
```

The `.format` method using named variable (useful for when sequence can't be depended upon):

```py
num = 6
mystr = "number is {num}".format(num=num)
print(mystr) # number is 6
```

The shorter `f-string` method: (thank you @mayur)

```py
num = 6
mystr = f"number is {num}"
print(mystr) # number is 6
```

Answer (score 1):

In each of your cases you have a `str` object. Its `.format` method returns the formatted string as a new object. Its `__mod__` method, which python calls when it sees the `%` operator, also returns a formatted string.

Functions and methods return anonymous objects. The context where they are called decide what happens next.

```
"number is {num}".format(num=num)
```

throws the result away.

```
some_variable = "number is {num}".format(num=num)
```

assigns the result.

```
some_function("number is {num}".format(num=num))
```

calls the function with the result as a parameter. `print` is not a special case - python doesn't do anything special with `print`.

Interestingly, f-strings like `f"number is {num}"` is compiled into a series of instructions that build the string dynamically.